# Excel Interop Save as is giving compatibility checker in excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Here is my code for `SaveAs` method:

```
m_FilePath="D:\Build\abc.xlsx"
m_objOpt=System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
m_objBook.SaveAs(m_FilePath, m_objOpt, m_objOpt,
    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
```

Now my question is not how to disable compatibility checker, that is already been answered many times. My question is why compatibility checker is coming at all. How does excel comes to know that the file is having traces of excel 2003. D:\Build is empty.

Comment: Shall I understand that you are opening a 2003-Excel file, performing certain modifications on it and just saving it as a 2007 (or higher) one by relying on this code?

Comment: I did not get you are point where you say opening a 2003-Excel file ?  Yes my develop environment has excel 2003 however the client using it has excel 2007

Comment: I meant a *.xls file. The question is: are you opening a *.xls file and saving it as a *.xlsx file by using this code?

Comment: @varocarbas no i am not opening any xls which already saved this is new instance which is created

Comment: Sorry internet problems will come back ASAP.

Comment: Apparently the internet connection will not come back any time soon and will not be able to help. Nonetheless my answer would have been something on the lines of what Chris has replied (+1 for him)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a specific version of Excel file, **you have to set the correct `FileFormat`** In the [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method.

Even if you set `.xls` in the path, if the file format is not specified, the running version of Excel will be used to save the file using the `SaveAs` method. It means that if you open an Excel 1997-2003 file with Excel 2007 or higher, the `SaveAs` method will save by default the file as Excel 2007 file if you don't set the `FileFormat` parameter.

> Optional Object. The file format to use when you save the file. For a
>   list of valid choices, see the FileFormat property. For an existing
>   file, the default format is the last file format specified; **for a new
>   file, the default is the format of the version of Excel being used**.

---

> What should be my FileFormat then if i want to save on both 2003 and
>   2007 depending on which excel is installed in the system?

Do not set the fileformat like you do or `xlWorkbookDefault` is the fileformat to use if you want to save on both 2003 and 2007 depending on which Excel is installed in the system.

What you need is to **detect the current version of Excel in order to set the correct extension (.xls or .xlsx) in the file name**. If the extension doesn't correspond to the real fileFormat which is used, you will have a message saying the extension doesn't correspond to the fileformat when you will open the file.

**Or**, the solution you propose seems to not set the extension in fileName, and let Excel complete the fileName with the correct extension based on the fileFormat that you specify after detecting the Excel version. Here you are using :

- 56 : `xlExcel8`            Excel8
- 46 : `xlXMLSpreadsheet`    Excel Spreadsheet format.

Link about [`FileFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

---

Also note that it won't prevent the compatibility checker to be displayed if you are using some Excel 2007 functionnality in an Excel 2003 file. To hide the message, you could set the [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts.aspx) property to `false`.

Comment: What should be my FileFormat then if i want to save on both 2003 and 2007 depending on which excel is installed in the system

Comment: @Shrivallabh Do not set the fileformat like you do or `xlWorkbookDefault` is the file format to use if you want to *save on both 2003 and 2007 depending on which excel is installed in the system*. What you need is to detect the current version of Excel in order to set the correct extension (.xls or .xlsx) in the file name. If the extension doesn't correspond to the real fileFormat which is used, you will have a message saying the extension doesn't correspond to the fileformat when you will open the file. If you want, I can update my answer with some way to do this.

Comment: @Shrivallabh But it won't prevent the compatibility checker to be displayed if you are using some Excel 2007 functionnality in a Excel 2003 file. To hide the message, you could set the [Application.DisplayAlerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts.aspx) property to False.

Comment: Glad I could Help :). I will edit my answer to reflect my last comments since I was not undestanding correctly what you was attempting to do.

Comment: For me it was an issue with the format as you've told at the very end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this :

```
if (11.0 < Convert.ToDouble(report.Version))
          {
              //For excel 2003
              workbook.SaveAs(filename, 56, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
           }
          else
          {
            //For excel 2007 and above
        workbook.SaveAs(filename, 51, misval, misval, misval, misval, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval);
            }
```