# Convert xlsx to xls issue

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to convert a `.xlsx` file to `.xls` and it seems to be working fine, however when I open the `.xls` file I get a warning message "

> The file you are trying to open 'filename', is in a different format
>   than specified by the file extension.
>
> Verify that the file is not corrupted and >from a trusted source before opening the >file.  Do you want to open the file now?"....

Everything looks fine when I open it, but I do not understand why this is happening.  My next step in this program is to import the data from the xls into SQL, but I am afraid this will cause issues for that.

Here is the line of code where I call the SaveAs method to change the file extension of the file.

```
wb.SaveAs("filename.xls", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
```

I initially just had

```
wb.SaveAs("filename.xls");
```

and after I got the error I did some more digging around and found the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, but does not seem to help.

Any info that could help me understand why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save as spreadsheet (OpenXml Format, `.xlsx`), use `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook`:

```
wb.SaveAs("filename.xlsx", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
```

To save as Excel 1997-2003 format (Biff, `.xls`), use `XlFileFormat.xlExcel8`:

```
wb.SaveAs("filename.xls", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
```

Make sure you set the **appropriate extension** (.xlsx or .xls), otherwise, you have the error you described.

See also my answer here [Excel Interop Save as is giving compatibility checker in excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417166/2387010)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I am pretty new to C# coding and this really helped me out.  Thank you for the link as well.  I will be working quite a bit with excel so this will come in handy also.