# how to solve the compatibility check when converting csv file to xls file?

Tags: c#, csv, xls

I have following function to convert csv file to xls file.

```
…
            Application objExcel = new Application();
            Workbooks objBooks = (Workbooks)objExcel.Workbooks;

            object objOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            try
            {
                objBooks.OpenText(inputPathNFileName, XlPlatform.xlWindows, 1, XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
                  false, false, false, true, false, false, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);
                Workbook objBook = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook;

                objBook.SaveAs(outPathNFileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);

                objBook.Close(false, objOpt, objOpt);
                objExcel.Quit();
                releaseObject(objBook);
                releaseObject(objBooks);
                releaseObject(objExcel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                …
            }
```

Now my problem is if my csv file has more than 65,536 rows, I will get a warning message at the SaveAs step, and all the rows after 65,536 will be chopped off. The warning message is “This workbook contains data in cells outside of the row and column limit of the selected format. Data beyond 256(IV) columns by 65,536 rows will not be saved."

How do I resolve this so that there is no limitation on the rows/columns of my csv file?

Comment: csv->xls? You can't get around it. It's a fundamental limit of the .xls format. If you want more rows, then you'd have to upgrade to .xlsx, which has a much higher limit.

Comment: Put a check in your code for the row count, and if > 65535, show a warning saying that Excel 2003 only supports up to 64k rows, please upgrade to Office 2010+ to use the .xlsx format.

Comment: I tried to change the outPathNFileName with xlsx extention, I still got the warnning at the SaveAs.

Answer (score 1):

I found this help here,
[Excel Interop Save as is giving compatibility checker in excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416867/excel-interop-save-as-is-giving-compatibility-checker-in-excel-2007)
I tried the solution it fixed my problem too.

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(objExcel.Version) > 11.0)
                {
                    objBook.SaveAs(outPathNFileName, 51, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);
                }
                else
                {
                    objBook.SaveAs(outPathNFileName, 56, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);
                }
```